# Unwanted attribute in code-first .NET database

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, ef-code-first

I've been working ono an ASP.NET MVC Web Application, and I have run into a problem I can't solve. I have the following classes:

```
public abstract class QuestionAbstract
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int ExamId { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public virtual Exam Exam { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<AnswerAbstract> Answers { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Variable> Variables { get; set; }
}

public abstract class AnswerAbstract
{
    [Key, Column(Order = 0)]
    public int ResponseId { get; set; }

    [Key, Column(Order = 1)]
    public int QuestionAbstractId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ResponseId")]
    public virtual Response Response { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("QuestionAbstractId")]
    public virtual QuestionAbstract Question { get; set; }
}
```

I would expect the database to include, for AnswerAbstract, attributes ResponseId and QuestionAbstractId. However, when the database is created, this is the result:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[AnswerAbstract] (
[ResponseId]          INT NOT NULL,
[QuestionId]          INT NOT NULL,
[QuestionAbstract_Id] INT NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.AnswerAbstract] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([ResponseId] ASC, [QuestionAbstractId] ASC),
CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.AnswerAbstract_dbo.QuestionAbstract_QuestionAbstractId] FOREIGN KEY ([QuestionId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[QuestionAbstract] ([Id]),
CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.AnswerAbstract_dbo.Response_ResponseId] FOREIGN KEY ([ResponseId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Response] ([Id]) ON DELETE CASCADE,
CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.AnswerAbstract_dbo.QuestionAbstract_QuestionAbstract_Id] FOREIGN KEY ([QuestionAbstract_Id]) REFERENCES [dbo].[QuestionAbstract] ([Id])
);
```

As you can see, an additional attribute (QuestionAbstract_Id) has been created, with the exact same functionality as the QuestionId I had coded (References the QuestionAbstract class). I suspect this has something to do with the Collection of AnswerAbstracts that QuestionAbstract has, but these types of relationships have not caused me problems before. Any ideas why this is happening? Obviously I left out other classes, since I don't think the problem is in another place, but if you need any other code, feel free to ask.

EDIT: Changed QuestionId to QuestionAbstractId. Still the same problem.

Comment: Try changing [ForeignKey("QuestionId")] to [ForeignKey("QuestionAbstractId")] and also public int QuestionId { get; set; } to public int QuestionAbstractId { get; set; }

Comment: As @AzharKhorasany mentioned, your property and class names have to be equal (QuestionAbstract foreign key can't be named QuestionId, it has to be named QuestionAbstractId) for EF to map them correctly.

Comment: Just tried it, didn't work. Seemed like a good guess, though

Answer (score 0):

Try changing

```
[ForeignKey("QuestionId")]
```

to

```
[ForeignKey("QuestionAbstractId")]
```

and also

```
public int QuestionId { get; set; }
```

to

```
public int QuestionAbstractId { get; set; }
```

Comment: Tried it, but still the same results.

Comment: @JuanCarlosGuzmánIslas i have posted the solution for this, you should try that one